# Android mobile app crashes when touching a job offer

Tags: support, bug, android-app

As soon as I tab on a job offer on the start page (recommended jobs) the mobile app for Android of stack exchange crashes. "Crashes" in this case means that it just gets closed. No error message or something. Just like someone hit the "back" button. Is this a bug?

Comment: Bug. Just don't touch them. :)